# IIB v10 and DB2 schemas no visible in the IIB Toolkit

Tags: db2, ibm-integration-bus

I'm testing the IIB developer edition on Windows 10.

IBM Integration Toolkit , Version: 10.0.0.18 and DB2 express-c 11.1.4.4

From the DB2 command line I can see the tables created (below the IIBADMIN schema). I'm logged with the IIBUSER Window user (that is not an ADMIN but is part of "mqbrkrs" and "mqm" groups)

The problem is that when I try to create a new "Database Definition File", I'm not able to see the DB schemas, so not able to select IIBADMIN schema.

[image]

FYI : I'm able to ping successfully the HRDB DB in the "Data Source Explorer" windows with the following settings:
[image]

I'm able to query the DB tables with a simple query like: `SELECT * FROM IIBADMIN.EMPLOYEE`

[image]

You can see a complete description of the scenario here:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/523428/iib-v10-and-db2-iibadmin-schema-no-visible-in-the/

Comment: Try additional property in the connection URL `currentSchema=IIBADMIN;`

Comment: Based on the system requirements report, that DB2 version is not supported: https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1376392102308&osPlatform=Windows#sw-4